# Pandas dates not showing on plot

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is from a cvs as follow:

```
         Date     Open     High     Low    Close  Adj Close    Volume
0  1996-01-01  4.06250  4.12500  3.8750  3.90625   3.093209   7048800
1  1996-02-01  3.84375  3.96875  3.5000  3.62500   2.870497  12864000
2  1996-03-01  3.50000  4.25000  3.5000  4.12500   3.266428   9526400
3  1996-04-01  4.06250  4.68750  4.0625  4.50000   3.563378   5693600
4  1996-05-01  4.40625  4.65625  4.1250  4.21875   3.340666  30480000
```

When I try to plot it there is no date on the bottom of the graph. Here is the code I am using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ABC.csv') #read cvs
df2 = df.loc[0:12] #select rows
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True) #set Date as index
df2['Close'].plot() #plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date is a string, so `matplotlib` so it wont automatically plot the labels. Change it to a `datetime` first and then plot.

```
import pandas as pd
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

---

Your plot:

```
df2 = df.loc[0:12]
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df2['Close'].plot()
```

[image]

Comment: currently this does not work, you still get bad placement with 'datetime64[ns]', name='DATE', freq=None)

Comment: @mathtick I don't understand your comment. This question was about the x-ticks not showing on the plot at all, not about optimizing the positioning. There are many other questions that discuss the latter. Though this seems to be moot as the original issue is no longer reproducible on `pandas 0.24`; the string dates will now display on the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Set your column date as datetime type :)

```
df = pd.read_csv('ABC.csv') #read cvs
df2 = df.loc[0:12] #select rows
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True) #set Date as index
df2['Close'].plot() #plot
```